# Where's the SELECT button?

Tags: ps4, mega-man-legacy-2

In Mega Man Legacy 2, some games like Mega Man 7 require the use of the SELECT button in order to access parts like the in-game store.

Since the PS4 does not include a SELECT button and there's a no SELECT in the configuration options, what button can be used for SELECT?

Comment: Have you tried the left/right sides of the touchpad?

Comment: I'll try that next, do you mean like swiping or pressing down?

Comment: from stuff I've seen, it looks like pressing it like a button on the sides functions as Start/Select for PS NOW titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For majority (if not all) PS1/PS2 titles, the Touchpad has been mapped for use as the Select/Start buttons.

For Mega Man Legacy 2 Collection in particular, [the manual](http://game.capcom.com/manual/RCC2/manual/en/ps4/1.html) suggests the entire touch pad is the Start button.